# How to make a modal for wordpress media link in Google Maps info window

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, pdf

I've got a project for which I have bulit a custom WP theme. Now one of the requirements for this projects was to make an interactive map based on Google Maps. The map shows a lot of markers in a specific area, and every marker when clicked, shows an info window. Each info window contains a list of WordPress media links like [this](http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Something.pdf):

And when you click one of those links, as usual it opens that specific PDF file in the browser. All of the files are PDF files.

Now the problem is, the client requests for those media links, when clicked, it should open in a modal window over the map,not into new browser tab.

Basically, he wants the PDF file to be loaded in the modal window instead of going to new tab to load the PDF.

I have never worked on it and i don't have any idea how to achieve that so any suggestions would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find that [How to display a pdf in a modal window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13305707/how-to-display-a-pdf-in-a-modal-window)
Maybe anyone know a better way.

Of course, replace jquery ui by an lightweight modal.