# How to show .pdf File in ShowModalDialog java Script

Tags: javascript

I have this code in jsp page:

```
function openw11(){
  var a='jungleRoadPolicyView.do?method=print&ref=83&policyId=<%=id%>&fishNum=<%=fishNum%>&fishDate=<%=fishDate%>';
  window.showModalDialog(a, self, 'status:no;resizable:yes;help:no;scroll:yes;width:1300;height:600');
}
```

JavaScript `showModalDialog` can't show pdf. I can't use `Window.open`, I need use to `showModalDialog`.

Comment: Please don't make everything bold in your questions, it looks like you're shouting and dramatically reduces the chance of anyone wanting to help you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display a pdf in a modal window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13305707/how-to-display-a-pdf-in-a-modal-window) and/or [Why is window.showModalDialog deprecated? What to use instead?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733962/why-is-window-showmodaldialog-deprecated-what-to-use-instead)