# Why are symbols showing up when i click 'view pdf' instead of he actual document?

Tags: wordpress, pdf

I'm doing some maintenance on a client's website and for some reason, on a couple of the PDFs featured on this specific page, when I click 'view PDF' I get this showing up instead of the actual PDF:
[View PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGpfb.png)

The code is below:

```
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row border border-second">
    <div class="col-sm-4"><a class="thumbnail" href="#Interest" data- 
    toggle="modal" data-target="#Interest">
    <img class="alignnone wp-image-2067" src="https://st- 
    anns.sheffield.sch.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Register-of-Pecuniary- 
    Interest.jpg" alt="" width="361" height="324">
    </a></div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="home-content-subtitle">Pecuniary Interest Register <img 
    class="pdf-icon-small img-responsive pull-right" src="/wp- 
    content/themes/bootstrap-canvas-wp/images/logos/pdf-icon-40x40.png" 
    alt="PDF"></div>
    See our Register for Pecuniary Interest here, listing all staff and 
    stating their status within the school.
    <p class="pull-right"><a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="https://st- 
    anns.sheffield.sch.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Register-of-Pecuniary- 
    Interest.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener" download="">Download 
    PDF</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="https://st- 
    anns.sheffield.sch.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/Register-of-Pecuniary- 
    Interest.pdf" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Interest">View PDF</a> 
    </p>
```

Comment: The 'symbols' are just the contents of the PDF file. PDF files are often binary, and that's what you are seeing there. I'd have to guess that something isn't detecting the PDF files as being PDF. I can't immediately see a reason why not though.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be looking for the same things as here?

[PDF file to be displayed on the dialog modal via bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35286303/pdf-file-to-be-displayed-on-the-dialog-modal-via-bootstrap)