# Convert html with styling (css) to pdf using PHP

Tags: php, html, css, pdf

I'm having some problems with my code! I am trying to convert my `html` invoice to a pdf invoice. After a payment is made the invoice is generated by the code below. Then the pdf file gets stored on the server and sent to the user by mail. This is the invoice I'm using: [invoice](https://gostreamlabs.com/front/html/pages/invoice.html). But when I convert the `html` to pdf the styles are not applied and the images don't show.

This is my `PHP` code to convert the `html` to a pdf using DomPDF:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
// reference the Dompdf namespace

$files = glob("/invoices/*.pdf");

foreach ($files as $file) include_once($file);

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait'); //landscape / portrait

$options = new Options();
$options->set('isRemoteEnabled', true);
$options->set('defaultFont', 'OpenSans');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

$output = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/invoices/" . $order_id . ".pdf", $output);
```

I think my problem lies with the `HTML` code.

## The problem with the css

I've tried a couple of things but none of these worked for me! Here's what I tried:

### Try 1

I've tried adding the `css` with a `link` tag like this:

`$html .= '<link type="text/css" href="/absolute/path/to/pdf.css" rel="stylesheet" />';`
I've also tried adding the `link` like a normal (in the head of the file), but both these times I didn't got it working.

### Try 2

I've also tried putting the `css` in a `style` tag in the `head` like this:

```
<style>
    /* my css here */
</style>
```

This didn't work eighter. I'm running out of ideas for the `css`.

## The problem with the images

When the `html` code contains a `img` like this:

```
<img src="/path/to/file" alt="" />
```

The image doesn't show up. Not even when I change the `src` to `https://pathtoimg.com/path/to/file/img.png`

Hopefully, you know the solution to the image and the `css` problems I'm struggling with! Thanks already for your effort!

#### Edit

I'm open to suggestions for other libraries or another approach. I still haven't found a stable solution so I may be looking in the wrong direction. If there are any other solutions out there please let me know!

Comment: This is exactly what a good question should look like on stackoverflow. 

About the image, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153139/dompdf-remote-image-is-not-displaying-in-pdf

Comment: Have you tried including the domain in the CSS href? I'm using a different library, [Knp Snappy](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy), for PDF generation, and that is what I need to do.

Comment: @MeesEgberts there's a link in my comment above.

Comment: dompdf:  "At its heart, dompdf is (mostly) a CSS 2.1 compliant HTML layout, Handles most CSS 2.1 and a few CSS3 properties, " id recommend just using something else more up to date. I use https://mpdf.github.io/ and have no problems whatsoever.

Comment: @fubar Thank you for your answer! I will take a look and give it a try!

Comment: @ikiK, Thank you for your answer! I will give it a try!

Comment: Have you use only css supported? [list of css supported](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/CSSCompatibility)

Comment: Where `$html` is declare?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini, it's included in the parameters of the method

Comment: @Pijpleiding I think it maybe weird, but you should try to use `style` tag on a head like  this one more time: Use `<style type="text/css" media="all">... your css here</style>` instead of `<style>... your css here</style>`. Hope it would work for you

Comment: @ThienHuynh I will give it a try! Thanks already!

Comment: Is it a possibility to store the svg's on your server?

Comment: I've had similar problems with pretty much all php PDF libraries over and over again. I'm sorry to tell you that none of them actually comes close to CSS specification comliancy. They're a very buggy rough approximation at best. If you have access to a server where you can install wkhtmltopdf (http://www.wkhtmltopdf.org), it may be your best shot, it is, however not a pdf library, but a unix tool.

Answer (score 10):

this won't be a full answer but I can at least help you with some of your problems regarding the images and explain why `Dompdf` won't work with the [invoice](https://gostreamlabs.com/front/html/pages/invoice.html).

### The issues

First of all, looking at your code, you also seem to use outdated functions `set(..)` and `$options` is also not passed to `Dompdf`. New examples can be found in [the develop branch](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/tree/develop) So we can clear the first problems with the following:

```php
// Include autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
// reference the Dompdf namespace

$files = glob("/invoices/*.pdf");

foreach ($files as $file) include_once($file);

// Reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
//Also reference the options namespace
use Dompdf\Options;

//First initialise the options
$options = new Options();
//This way of setting options is new see: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/2181

$options->setIsRemoteEnabled(true);
$options->setDefaultFont('OpenSans');
// Instantiate and use the dompdf class with the options
$dompdf = new Dompdf($options);

// Load content from html file
$html = ...; //file_get_contents("invoice.html");
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait'); //landscape / portrait



// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();
$output = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/invoices/" . $order_id . ".pdf", $output);
```

With this code we get the following result:

(Used a `jsFiddle` to prevent the images from taking up too much space. Now they are inline)

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/86xNQ.png" width="600px" />
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/coyyn.png" width="600px" />
```

This way, at least the logo is rendered. So what is left?
Looking at the result, only part of the html is rendered properly. So the css files are in fact working. But the only problem here is that the invoice uses, among other properties, `flex` like `display: flex` and such. This, however, is not supported, yet, as can be seen [in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/971). That is why not all of the elements will be rendered properly.

As of now, a possible solution would be to take a screenshot with `html2canvas` and 'convert' it into a pdf with `jsPdf` as can be seen [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62656987/8902440). But I'm not sure if that is a possibility for your use case.

### Possible solution

Anyhow, since [Snappy has no support for flex as well](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy/issues/327), I have created an adapted example for this specific case with [`html2canvas`](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com) (which does support flex) and [`jsPdf`](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF).

First of all on, for example, `invoice.php` add the following php function on top of the page. This function `toBase64` will convert any 'foreign' svg to a local base64 string, which can be handled by `html2canvas`:

```php
function toBase64($url) {
  $data = file_get_contents($url);
  $base64 = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' . base64_encode($data);
  return $base64;
}
```

To only make a pdf of the actual invoice, add `id="invoice"` to `<div class="card-body p-5 p-md-7 p-lg-11">` Which seems to be the container of the invoice.

To use the php function effectively, change the `<img>` tag with the logo to this:

```php
<img class="mb-2" src="<?= toBase64('https://streamlabs.nyc3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/assets/svg/logos/logo-short.svg')?>" alt="Logo">
```

Then change the `onclick` function of the "print" button like so:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info transition-3d-hover" onclick="showPDF();">
          <i class="fas fa-print mr-2"></i>
          Print
        </button>
```

At last, add this javascript function at the bottom of the page:

```js
function showPDF() {
   //Create screenshot of body
   html2canvas(document.getElementById('invoice'), {scale: 3,scrollY: -window.scrollY}).then(canvas => {
      var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
      //add the image to, and create the pdf
      var pdf = new jsPDF('P', 'pt', [canvas.width, canvas.height]);
      pdf.addImage(imgData, 'jpeg', 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      //set the pdfFinal to be later downloaded
      //convert the pdf to a base64 string to make it uploadable
      let output = btoa(pdf.output());
      $.ajax({
         method: "POST",
         url: "upload.php",
         data: {data: output, fileName: 'order-123.pdf'},
      }).done(function(data) {
         console.log('all done');
         //view errors
         console.log(data);
      });
        
        //Then, let the client print the document. 
        window.print();
      });
}
```

This basically takes a screenshot of the invoice, creates a base64 string of it, and puts the base64 string in the pdf and uploads it to the server.
In this example `upload.php` is the page which actually saves the pdf on the server like so:

```php
if(isset($_POST['data'])){
  $data = base64_decode($_POST['data']);
  if (isset($_POST['fileName'])) {
    $file = $_POST['fileName'];
  } else {
    $file = "order-" . rand(10,1000) . ".pdf";
  }
 file_put_contents($file, $data);
 echo "Succes";
} else {
  echo "No Data Sent";
}
exit();
```

It will create the following pdf:

```html
Chrome and firefox
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4gBc.png" width="600px" />
Safari
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2x8K.png" width="600px" />
```

As you can see, it works better on chrome and firefox than on safari, because `fontawesome` and `html2canvas` don't work quite well together on safari (don't know why).

I hope I could clear up some things. If you have any questions, please comment!

### Edit

Because I couldn't find any other 'Dom to pdf' on the serverside which support 'flex' I've created an example which works on the client side.

Comment: Nice answer! This will certainly help people out!

Comment: Can't you create a pdf from the image and store it on the server? This way you can send the invoice to the client by mail!

Comment: @MeesEgberts you mean taking a screenshot, sending that image to the server, and then creating a pdf from it on the server?

Comment: Yes, something like that! This way you can have the pdf file stored on the server and send it to the client!

Comment: @MeesEgberts I don't yet know how to do it, but perhaps someone can edit my answer to accomadate that

Answer (score 1):

I used mpdf before, so decided to give it a try. Using xampp, php 7.4.8 on my windows 10

```
 composer require mpdf/mpdf
```

Code

```
<?php
//Fadil Eldin
//8/16/2020
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$html = file_get_contents('https://gostreamlabs.com/front/html/pages/invoice.html');
$mpdf->WriteHTML("");
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
?>
```

Output
[image]

second page
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Your **HTML** start with 
`<!DOCTYPE html>` 
and also contain the following tag in head 
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>` 
Update **Dompdf** script with following

```
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->set_option( 'isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);
$dompdf->set_option( 'isRemoteEnabled', true);
$dompdf->set_option( 'defaultMediaType', 'all' );
$dompdf->set_option( 'isFontSubsettingEnabled', true );
$dompdf->set_option('defaultFont', 'OpenSans');
$dompdf->loadHtml( $html, 'UTF-8' );
$dompdf->render();
// Attachment value 1 for download and 0 for preview PDF
//$dompdf->stream( 'testing.pdf', array( 'Attachment' => 1 ) ); 
$output = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/invoices/" . $order_id . ".pdf", $output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please include `$dompdf->set_base_path('localhost/exampls/style.css');`

```
<?php
require_once "dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php";
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();

$html ="
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" href="localhost/exampls/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr >
    <td class='abc'>testing table</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class='def'>Testng header</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>";

$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->set_base_path('localhost/exampls/style.css');
$dompdf->stream("hello.pdf");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try converting your images to base64 and then add as url ? It would make it independent to urls as well.

this can help you to convert to base64
[How to convert an image to base64 encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967515/how-to-convert-an-image-to-base64-encoding)

for CSS i tried with  and it works for me.