# How to capture all submitted data on my website form n download the data neatly placed in a pdf template by click of a button?

Tags: python, html, forms, odoo-15

We are on Odoo 15. So on the website i need a way users can (after clicking submit) click on a button and download the information the just submitted on a template with more fields. See we are trying to offer needy kids scholarships and we need a way they can download a pdf with the same information they submit on the website plus extra fields e.g

1. header with two columns, one for our logo and location info other for QR image
2. footer with two columns again. One for a local authority figure from their area to sign and affirm the individual's identity, the ohter column for the same local authority figure to stamp so we are sure it's the legitimate officer.
   I have the Forms module by Nova Code installed and am trying to figure out how to do this?
   How is this module integrated with odoo? // how do i capture posted data? // How do i print out this posted data // How do i prepare this template that users will be downloading?

I tried having two buttons, one hidden the other with some JS code logic to download a file first from a URL (

```
<a href="./abcf32x.pdf" download="How-to-download-file.pdf">
    <button>Download File</button>
</a>
```

) and simultaneously trigger the click of our initial (now hidden button) and submit our form. The download part worked it downloaded a file i pointed to with url but the form never submitted (Plus what i need is a way to print out data that user posted...not just a pdf file that they have to fill out all over again)

Am not sure what am missing? Or doing Wrong?

Thanks guys ur all my Heros :)

Comment: [Here it is done using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62663905/convert-html-with-styling-css-to-pdf-using-php/62803328#62803328) it might give you start on how to tackle this problem.

Comment: Chiel thanks , unfortunately odoo framework uses python and does NOT support <php> ...thanks though Any other ideas?    :)