# Creating a Simple PDF Modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, simplemodal

I would like a simple pdf modal where I could write: `'The sky is
 blue'` click here (links to pdf) and then the pdf modal opens up once clicked.  found a sample online thats similar except it has a picture plus a picture modal
comes up. 
I want the picture to be replaced by a button and clicking the button opens the pdf modal.

What should I change?

Im new to this web stuff. I've experimented and even had a cigarette even though I don't smoke.

Heres the HTML:

```
       <!-- Trigger the Modal -->
       <img id="myImg" src="pic4377.jpg" alt="RESOLUTION" width="300"     height="200">
       <!-- The Modal -->
       <div id="myModal" class="modal">
     **strong text**<!-- The Close Button -->
       <span class="close"    onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>
       <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
       <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
       <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
       <div id="caption"></div>
       </div>
```

Heres the CSS:

```
       /* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */
       #myImg {
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 0.3s;
         }

         #myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

          /* The Modal (background) */
         .modal {
          display: none; /* Hidden by default */
          position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
          z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
          padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
          left: 0;
          top: 0;
          width: 100%; /* Full width */
          height: 100%; /* Full height */
          overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
          background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
          background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
          }

          /* Modal Content (Image) */
          .modal-content {
          margin: auto;
          display: block;
          width: 80%;
          max-width: 700px;
          }

         /* Caption of Modal Image (Image Text) - Same Width as the Image */
          #caption {
             margin: auto;
                 display: block;
               width: 80%;
           max-width: 700px;
           text-align: center;
              color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */
.modal-content, #caption { 
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    modalImg.alt = this.alt;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "pdf modal"?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me what you mean with "pdf modal" but I am assuming you are trying to show the contents of a pdf file inside a modal?

Perhaps following question contains some answers for you:

[How to display a pdf in a modal window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13305707/how-to-display-a-pdf-in-a-modal-window)

Comment: A modal window opens with iframe pdf view inside it.

Comment: Have you tried it with `<iframe src="link_to_pdf"></iframe>` in the modal? We will need more details about what exactly you are struggling with. Is it opening the modal from a button instead of with an image. Or is the problem showing the PDF in the modal? Or something else?